# I can connect to Oracle programmatically but not from VS Server Explorer?

Tags: c#

Using Oracle ODP this works

```
        OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=XE;User Id=hr;Password=hr;";
```

But when I use Visual Studio Server Explorer entering ODP and same parameters as above (copy and paste from advanced properties)

```
DATA SOURCE=XE;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=False;USER ID=HR
```

It says "TNS: could not resolve the connect identifier"
Why ?

This is my TNSName.ora

```
XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = Whatever)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using machinename/instancename to connect.  For instance Whatever/XE for "DATA SOURCE".

EDIT: Also make sure you have defined a providerName.

providerName="System.Data.OracleClient"

I think you can also use Oracle.DataAccess.Client if you have the oracle client and libs installed.

Comment: Well it's better :)
Except it shows another kind of error "Data Provider Internal Error (-3000) [System.String]"

Answer (score 1):

This actually solved my issue:

For Data source name, I used: host/service_name